# Ads appearing before (on top of) questions?

Tags: support, advertising

I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841401/how-to-find-acceptable-mse-mean-square-error-based-on-given-observables) on Mathematics, and was very troubled by the ad appearing on top of the question, as well as to the right of the question.  Since when are ads permitted to be banners between the title of a question and its answer?

I've never encountered this before, so I doubt it is a browser issue.  I'd just like clarification as to whether this will become standard practice on SE sites.  This is the banner appearing atop the question I linked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You have a suspension on that site, which means that you've lost your [200-reputation privilege to see reduced ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) on that site.

This type of banner advertisement is suppressed by default if you have that privilege, as noted in the help page linked above:

> After you achieve this privilege, the two "leaderboard" style ads will be automatically suppressed from question pages when you are logged in.
>
> [image]
>
> The areas in red are the leaderboard ads. The areas in gray are the sidebar ads, which will remain visible.

Once your suspension expires tomorrow, the ad will be gone again, so long as you've not opted to keep it visible in your user profile settings.

Answer (score 6):

Ads that appear between the question title and the actual question are nothing new.  Also, [you are suspended on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy), so you have lost the privilege to see [reduced ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads).  So no, it isn't by design.