# When a suspended user clicks on "follow" on a question, it says "Following" even though suspended user cannot follow questions

Tags: bug, account-suspension, follow-post

Example:

[image]

This was originally closed as a duplicate of a different bug report reporting that suspended users cannot follow posts, as it was believed that that was the issue and this would be made obsolete once that was fixed. However, that bug report was dismissed as by design, so this is still an issue that stands on its own.

Comment: It's actually a bug that suspended users can't follow/unfollow posts: [Suspended users cannot follow/unfollow posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356557/suspended-users-cannot-follow-unfollow-posts)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, not a dupe, here the pb is what is been shown to users.

Comment: A related bug is that [Following/UnFollowing isn't mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/282094) in the FAQ section on suspensions.

Comment: From the suggested dupe (emphasis added): "After clicking the 'follow' link under the post, **it changes to 'following'** (and vice versa) along with the error popup but after refreshing the page the follow status goes back to the original setting."